# How to check some maven dependencies compatibility (spring-oxm)

Tags: spring, maven, dependencies, compatibility

Im wondering, I want to bump the version of spring-oxm from 5.2.10.RELEASE to the latest 5.3.15 to not have the vulnerabilities, but im worried about the compatibility with my spring-boot. Currentrly using boot version 2.3.5.RELEASE

Thanks!

Comment: Simplest solution upgrade your spring boot version to the most recent 2.6.2 (2.3.5... is a bit old)...

Comment: Don't. Don't start to mix jars/modules from different versions of a framework. That will lead to incompatibility issues and strange to debug results. I would strongly suggest to upgrade to a new Spring Boot version (2.3 is old and not supported anymore).

Comment: I cant just upgrade to new spring, because it needs client approval. I might try to argue to get new version, but our infrastructure is huge, and testing the new version would take a LOT of time and resources.  spring-oxm is just in like 2-3 microservices.  Anyway, where can i check which versions are compatiblw with eachother ? Like, if i have 5.2.10 right now, what is the highest version i can use to be still safely compatible with the 2.3.5 spring boot ?